# Reverse Bits JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

The problem is standard but the solution in JavaScript takes a lot more effort to code.

I got the solution but my answer is coming half of what is desired.

**Problem Description**

Reverse the bits of a 32-bit unsigned integer A.

**Problem Constraints**

0 <= A <= 2^32

**Input Format**

The first and only argument of input contains an integer A.

**Output Format**

Return a single unsigned integer denoting minimum xor value.

**Example Input**

```
Input 1:
0
Input 2:
3
```

**Example Output**

```
Output 1:
0
Output 2:
3221225472
```

**My solution**

```
function modulo(a, b) {
        return a - Math.floor(a/b)*b;
}
function ToUint32(x) {
    return modulo(parseInt(x), Math.pow(2, 32));
}
function revereBits(A){
    A = A.toString(2);
    while (A.length < 31){
        A = "0"+A;
    }
    var reverse = 0;
    var NO_OF_BITS = A.length;
    for(var i = NO_OF_BITS; i >= 1; i--){
        var temp = (parseInt(A, 2) & (1 << i - 1));
        if(temp){
            reverse |= 1 << (NO_OF_BITS - i);

        }
    } 
    if( reverse << 1 < 0 ) reverse = ToUint32(reverse << 1);
    return reverse;

}
```

Now, in the line

```
 if( reverse << 1 < 0 ) reverse = ToUint32(reverse << 1);
```

You see that I  have to double the answer. **I cannot, however, get the part of why is this required.**

I took the approach from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-an-efficient-c-program-to-reverse-bits-of-a-number/

Had to make few adjustments to it. For example, run the loop from 31 to 1 rather than 0 to 31. The latter gives negative values in first left shift operation for i = 0 itself.

Can someone please help in fixing this solution and point to the problem in this?

UPDATE - Problem is related to Bit manipulation. So guys, please don't answer or comment for anything consisting of in-built string functions of Javascript. Cheers!

Comment: Once you've built A as a string, you could split the string into an array, call `.reverse()` on that, join it back together, and then pass it to `parseInt(A, 2)`.

Comment: This: `parseInt(a.toString(2).padStart(32, 0).split('').reverse().join(''), 2)`

Comment: Not looking for in-built function solutions

Comment: I'd say the problem is related to not having unsigned integers in javascript.

Comment: Yes @orithena That is an issue. That's the very reason `ToUint32 ` is there as an extra function. But my concern is the last part where I have to do one extra left shift. (reverse << 1). It's bugging me

Comment: @kushalvm Probably because you've got an off-by-one error somewhere. You work on a string (that is representing bits) of length 31 instead of 32. I think your series of off-by-one-errors start at this fact, probably because you tried to correct the rest to work despite that initial error.

Comment: @kushalvm Or, in other words: Your `while (A.length < 31)` fills up the string to a length of 31, meaning you got the elements 0..30 in it. Based on your requirements, I think you want a length of 32, with the elements indexed as 0..31. (By the way, I think your question would be better on codereview.stackexchange.com -- here on stackoverflow, people answer to give the best solution, but I think that you want a hint on what you did wrong in that particular way of solving it.

Comment: @kushalvm By the way, here's the condensed form of your general method, without using Strings: `var inp = 0xf30505c3; var out = 0; for(i = 0; i < 32; i++) { out |= ((inp & (1<<i)) != 0) << (31-i); }; console.log((inp>>>0).toString(2)); console.log((out>>>0).toString(2));`

Comment: @orithena such a question might not be considered [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on CR because "_We expect you, as the author, to understand why the code is written the way that it is._" and henceforth a post like this on that site might likely be closed for that reason.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Ah, okay, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do it using just bitwise operators, and a typed array to solve the sign issue:

**Update**
Changing slightly approach of the `rev` function after @bryc comment. Since having multiple function for "history" purpose makes the answer difficult to read, I'm putting first the latest code.
However, I'm keeping the comments about the different steps – the rest can be found in the edit history.

```
function rev(x) {
    x = ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555) | ((x & 0x55555555) << 1);
    x = ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333) | ((x & 0x33333333) << 2);
    x = ((x >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F) | ((x & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4);
    x = ((x >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF) | ((x & 0x00FF00FF) << 8);
    x = (x >>> 16) | (x << 16);

    return x >>> 0;
}
```

This is the same code you would write in other languages as well to reverse bits, the only difference here is the addition of the typed array.

As @harold pointed out in the comment, the [zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) returns an unsigned (it's the only bitwise operator to do so) therefore we can omit the typed array and just add `>>> 0` before the `return`.

In fact, doing `>>> 0` is commonly used to simulate the `ToUint32` in JS polyfilll; e.g.:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

```
    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal method
    //    of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;
```

Comment: Yes Sir, But this is complicated and won't strike to mind. Can you help fix a bug in my code? I believe, I'm on right track

Comment: I thought the question was how to reverse bit in JavaScript: this is how you reverse bits in JavaScript, just using bitwise operators. There is nothing complicated in that, is the same code you can find in C as well and any languages that can deal with bits. If you want to reverse bits in your own way is cool, but it's not efficient neither is how you do it in JS (or any other languages).
Bottom line: you might want to edit the title of your question, it doesn't reflect what you want to obtain.

Comment: You meant the zero-fill? That's right, is unsigned: if we do a `>>> 0` in the return, we can omit the typed array.

Comment: Well I meant `(x & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16` etc, shouldn't those shifts be the `>>>` variant, to avoid the sign bit spreading all over the place?

Comment: No, in that case it won't work: the internal bits are the same, it's just the representation that is different: so if you do `(x & 0xFFFF0000) >>> 16` but then you have a `|` (e.g `(x & 0x0000FFFF)  <<  16 | (x & 0xFFFF0000) >>> 16)` then from unsigned you revert to signed.
You can also check doing `console.log(rev(3), 0|rev(3)) // the first in unsigned, the second signed`.
So you're right about the nature of zero-fill right shift, but it's useful only if you're doing the `>>> 0` before return the value.

Comment: @ZER0 I know it reverts to signed, doesn't matter. The shifts however must be unsigned, otherwise they copy the sign bit all over the place. You can put in `rev(0x80000000)` or something similar to see it go wrong, using `>>>` fixes that.

Comment: @ZER0 Both your functions fail for `rev(0xH0000000)` with `H > 0`. You need to use `>>>` instead of `>>` everywhere. You don't need to use `Uint32Array` or `>>> 0`.

Comment: @ZER0 Actually you're right you still need the `>>> 0` or `Uint32Array` for the `rev(0xXXXXXXXH)` with `H = 0bBBB1` case sorry. However the bit shifts should be unsigned for the `rev(0xHXXXXXXX)` case.

Comment: Neither of your answers work. `0xf4acfb13` should return `0xc8df352f` but instead it returns `0xffffffff`

Comment: Hi @bryc thank you for the comment. Let me know if the updated answer still have any issue with 32 bit numbers.

Comment: @ZER0 Better, but still some issues: `0x04C11DB7` should be `0xEDB88320`. `0x741B8CD7` should be `0xEB31D82E`. `0x814141AB` should be `0xD5828281`. Thanks!

Comment: @bryc my bad, I had a typo: the last right shift should also be a  zero-fill right shift (answer updated)

Answer (score 4):

```js
function reverseBits(integer, bitLength) {
  if (bitLength > 32) {
    throw Error(
      "Bit manipulation is limited to <= 32 bit numbers in JavaScript."
    );
  }

  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < bitLength; i++) {
    result |= ((integer >> i) & 1) << (bitLength - 1 - i);
  }

  return result >>> 0; // >>> 0 makes it unsigned even if bit 32 (the sign bit) was set
}
```

Comment: What's up with the "semicolon-police" adding semicolons to my code? It's not C++...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function reverseBits(num) {

    let reversed = num.toString(2);
    const padding = "0";
    reversed = padding.repeat(32 - reversed.length) + reversed;
    return parseInt(reversed.split('').reverse().join(''), 2);
}

console.log(reverseBits(0)); // 0
console.log(reverseBits(3)); // 3221225472
```

Comment: Not looking for in-built function solutions

Comment: I didn't change anything. My solution approach says everything

Comment: @kushalvm Nothing in the question says anything about not using "in-built functions" before the edit.

Comment: The way problem is described and the reference link for `geeksforgeeks` should say a volume that this is a problem-solving question rather than achieving any workable solution. The official term is competitive programming. Try it sometime!

Comment: @kushalvm Read [ask]. All information relevant to the question must be in the question itself. Please don't condescend to others who are trying to help make this the best site for great questions and answers.